# Why does my variable say it is unassigned when it is assigned?

Tags: c#-4.0, compiler-errors, variable-assignment

I'm am helping convert VB code to C#. In the C# code, I have an error saying that one of my variables is unassigned. When I right click (in Visual Studios 2013) and click on Go to Definition it brings me to its declaration where it is clearly being assigned to null. I have even tried assigning it to something else besides null.

Here is the declaration and it being set to null:

```
DataSet set5 = new DataSet();
set5 = null;
```

Here is where it is being called and where I get the error:

```
try 
{
    wires.grdInser.DataSource = set5.Tables[0];//Being called here
} catch (Exception exception92) 
{
    ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception92);
    Exception exception46 = exception92;
    ProjectData.ClearProjectError();
}
```

There is a bunch of code in-between these two pieces of code, but I don't think the scope the variable is being called in is an issue since the "Go to Definition" takes me directly to the definition. Could the issue be because it is inside a try/catch statement? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The set5 variable is null, so it doesn't contain Tables[0].

Comment: @PhillipXT but I have tried setting it to things that other DataSet variables in the code have been set to and I still receive the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead, just to get rid of the error, then you can figure out what you need to do from there:

```
DataSet set5 = new DataSet();
DataTable x = new DataTable();
set5.Tables.Add(x);
```

Get rid of the `set5 = null` statement.

Now your other function should be able to see `Tables[0]`.

Comment: The same error is still popping up. When I put the line: 'wires.grdInser.DataSource = set5.Tables[0];' right under what you suggested, it doesn't give the error.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line `wires.grdInser.DataSource = set5.Tables[0];`, check which part of that line has the error, and make sure the values of each variable are what you expect them to be.  There could be another section of your code that's changing something - hard to know without seeing the whole thing.

Comment: The piece of code between these to pieces expands over 4,000 lines so it's definitely possible that could be the case. I was never taught how to debug, I'm still newish to programming, but is it possible to debug when the program won't execute due to compile errors? I was under the impression that breakpoints only stop the program when you reach that part of code when running the compiled program.

Comment: The error we're discussing won't cause a compile error, so if you're getting one it's coming from somewhere else.  You will have to fix those first before you can debug this line of code.